# EF: How to reuse newly created foreign key

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am new to EF and stuck here in one of my scenerio, where I need to create or use keys from a reference table.
User can create a new record in reference table or can use existing one. For that I have created my Entity model as shown below:

```
 Public class MaterialLineEntry()
 {
    EntryNumber = 0,
    OrganisationID=0,
    Organisation  Organisation 
  };
```

AND

```
 Public class Organisation ()
  {
     ID = 0,                            
     Description = "Test",
     EntityChangeStatus ;
   };
```

These line entries are defined inside another entity called Report

```
Public class Report()
{
         List<  MaterialLineEntry> materilaLineEntries;
 };
```

Everything works fine if I enter the details as shown below and attach the object(report), to the UnitOfWork and commet it. Entity framework creates a record in reference table and use the newly generated foreign key to enter it in line entry table.

```
Report report =new Reort();
        report. materilaLineEntries.Add(new MaterialLineEntry()
            {
                EntryNumber=1,
                OrganisationID=0,
                Organisation=new Organisation()
                {
                    ID = 0,
                    Description = "Test",
                    EntityChangeStatus = EntityChangeStatus.Unchanged,
                }
            })
```

but when I add two objects to the line entry with same organisation details:

```
 report. materilaLineEntries.Add(new MaterialLineEntry()
            {
                EntryNumber=1,
                OrganisationID=0,
                Organisation=new Organisation()
                {
                    ID = 0,
                    Description = "Test",
                    EntityChangeStatus = EntityChangeStatus.Unchanged,
                }
            })
```

it should use the previously created foreign key(as I may have a unique constrant).
As I am trying to insert duplicate record in a reference table. What I need here is, Entity Frame work should add the first organization details and should use the same ID for consequent occurences of same record (in this case Description column).

Please help me geeting this solved. Thanks in advance.
(I have thought of adding the data in foreign table one by one and using the foreign key further, but I guess it is a bad idea).

Comment: I finally got solution f0r this, we shud set the foreign key/ reference object once and EF is smart enough to use newly generated identity of reference table for any consicutive use (in case we havnt set the foreign key/ reference object )

Answer (score 0):

You have foreignkey "OrganizationId" in the MaterialLineEntry. To resuse a existing Organization you have to assign an exisitng id to OrganizationId only. e.g.

```
report. materilaLineEntries.Add(new MaterialLineEntry()
            {
                EntryNumber=1,
                OrganisationID=0,//Id of a exsiting organization

            });
```

EDIT : Full code

```
Report report =new Reort();
var org=new Organisation()
                {
                    Description = "Test",
                    EntityChangeStatus = EntityChangeStatus.Unchanged,
                };
        report. materilaLineEntries.Add(new MaterialLineEntry()
            {
                EntryNumber=1,
                OrganisationID=0,
                Organisation=org
            });
        report.SaveChanges();
        report. materilaLineEntries.Add(new MaterialLineEntry()
                {
                    EntryNumber=1,
                    OrganisationID=org.Id,//Id of a exsiting organization

                });
       report.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks nhrobin for your reply, the solution works fine if I add a existing "OrganizationId", but in my case I need to create a new organisation and assign it , in consicutive line entries. say for Line entry 1 I need a new organisation "XYZ" and for line entry 2 I need the same organization "XYZ".

Comment: this is a good idea, but in my scenerion I can only send the whole object to DAL, where I can Save the Changes or Commit the changes. so I need to construct the object befor sending it to DAL layer. I tried by creating a new Ogranisation object for first line entry and keeping null for second, it owrked well ;-), but now if I have three line entries with first as a new object, second as null and again third a new one , but it gives me exception (Unable to determine the principal end of 'MaterialLineEntery_Organisation' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key)